# Radiobuttons in tkinter already selected when run

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create an app in python. Most of the times, all radio buttons except the first one is already selected, and the first one selected after hovering. Please note that this happens 9 out of 10 times, and once it works as intended.

Code is included below.
EDIT: Code repasted. I think it went off during copy-paste. Sorry!

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

i = 0
#for i in range(0, 10):
#    print i

macro_sheet_names = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print len(macro_sheet_names)

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()

def sel():
    selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)
    print ('Tab selected: ' + str(var.get()))
    root.destroy()
#   sys.exit()
#   root.withdraw()

i = 0
for i in range (0, len(macro_sheet_names)):
    R = Radiobutton(root, text = macro_sheet_names[i], variable = var, value = i, command = sel)
    R.pack(anchor = W)


label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

print ('Exiting...')
sys.exit()
```

Comment: your indentation is off - please fix it.

Comment: That's odd. Once I fix your indentation errors the code behaves as expected for me. Are you running it directly in the terminal, or inside IDLE, or some other IDE?

Comment: Hi, fixed indentation in question. Still behaving the same way.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works on Python 3 with modification. Try this:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

i = 0
#for i in range(0, 10):
#    print i

macro_sheet_names = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print (len(macro_sheet_names))

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()

def sel():
    selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)
    print ('Tab selected: ' + str(var.get()))
    root.destroy()
    #   sys.exit()
    #   root.withdraw()

i = 0
for i in range (0, len(macro_sheet_names)):
    R = Radiobutton(root, text = macro_sheet_names[i], variable = var, value = i, command = sel)
    if i == 0: R.select ()
    R.pack(anchor = W)


label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

print ('Exiting...')
sys.exit()
```

It simply selects the first radio-box automatically.

Comment: why would you not use `var.set(0)`?

Comment: Hey, that worked! Although the program doesn't exit by printing 'Exiting...' most of the times. Could you help me figure out what is wrong there?

Comment: It's hard to tell what it is you changed. Would you mind expounding on that?

Comment: Added the line if i == 0: R.select()

Comment: I have never used Enthought Canopy but you may like to try adding before 'sys.exit', 'import time time.sleep (0.1)'. This will simply wait a 10th of a second before exiting. This shouldn't make a difference but is worth trying.